# Rails smart_listing gem implicit sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, smart-listing

I implemented impliciting sorting as advised in README. https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/.
 But when I click sortable table headers(which appear as link) nothing happens. If I open that link in new tab, table gets sorted.

Comment: Look at the demo example given [SmartListing Sorting](http://showcase.sology.eu/smart_listing#sorting), maybe you forget about the `js` file so your server only render the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for suggestion.

solved the issue by moving **//= require smart_listing** line in assets to the bottom before **//= require_tree .** line.